# Using SystemVerilog structs that contain parameters as input/output ports to a module

Tags: struct, parameters, verilog, system-verilog

My struct contains parameters that vary per module. I'd like to use this struct to pass input/outputs to these modules. I'm using this for design so it has to be synthesizable and my toolchain doesn't support Interfaces unfortunately.

For example:

```
`ifdef MY_STRUCTS
`define MY_STRUCTS
typedef struct packed {
  logic [PARAMETER_VAL-1:0] field1;
  logic [PARAMETER1_VAL-1:0] field2;
} myStruct_t;
`endif

module top #(
  parameter PARAMETER_VAL = 8;
  parameter PARAMETER1_VAL = 16;
) (
  input myStruct_t in_packet,
  output myStruct_t out_packet,
);
```

Unfortunately, this seems to be a chicken-or-egg problem. The struct definition can't be compiled because it relies on the module parameters to define it. However, the input/output declarations can't be declared because it relies on the struct to know what to declare.

Does anyone have a solution to this? Would definitely appreciate suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Potentially you can also use a parameterized interface.

Disclaimer: the following code works with synopsys but fails with cadence in eda playground. I think that Cadence is in violation of the standard here (They might have fixed it in the latest version).

Anyway, here is the example

```
interface top_if #(int PARAMETER_VAL = 8, PARAMETER1_VAL = 16) ();

   typedef struct packed {
      logic [PARAMETER_VAL-1:0] field1;
      logic [PARAMETER1_VAL-1:0] field2;
   } myStruct_t;

   myStruct_t in_packet, out_packet;

   modport in (input in_packet);
   modport out (output out_packet);

endinterface

module caller();
   top_if #(8,16) top_if();
   always_comb top_if.in_packet = '{11, 22};

   top top(top_if.in, top_if.out);

   logic [top_if.PARAMETER1_VAL-1:0] field2;
   always_comb field2 = top_if.out_packet.field2;
   always @* begin
      $display("out.field2=%0d", field2);
   end
endmodule


module top(
           top_if in,
           top_if out
           );
   logic [in.PARAMETER_VAL-1:0] field1;

   always_comb field1 = in.in_packet.field1;
   always_comb out.out_packet = '{field1, field1+55};

   always @* begin
      $display("input.field1=%d", field1);
   end

endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately, our toolchain does not support SV interfaces in the design. I wish it did as that would be the proper way to do this....

Comment: Also, how do I access structs defined in an interface within the logic of the module were I to use this?

Comment: do you mean as the typedef for declaration in the module? I do not think that you can.

Comment: Hmm, that's a little confusing then. I ideally want to be able to use the same struct to generate and also to send to other modules. As well as flop them in between. Structs were perfect for that except this wrinkle of parameter usage....

Comment: you can send the whole interface, as in the example. You can access the fields of the structs and the interface parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

Instead of passing a list of parameter values, pass a single struct typedef with the field widths you need. You would likely want to use the struct in the upper level anyway.

```
module upper;
typedef struct packed {
  logic [7:0] field1;
  logic [16:0] field2;
} myStruct_t;
my_Struct in, out;
lower #(.T(my_Struct_t) ins1 (in, out);
...
endmodule
module lower #(type T) (
    input T in_packet,
    output T out_packet,
);
...
endmodule
```

Create the struct type inside the lower level module, but keep the ports as packed arrays. This works because the struct is packed as well.

```
module top #(
  parameter PARAMETER_VAL = 8;
  parameter PARAMETER1_VAL = 16;
) (
  input logic [PARAMETER_VAL+PARAMETER_VAL1-1:0] in,
  output logic [PARAMETER_VAL+PARAMETER_VAL1-1:0] out,
);

typedef struct packed {
  logic [PARAMETER_VAL-1:0] field1;
  logic [PARAMETER1_VAL-1:0] field2;
} myStruct_t;
 myStruct_t in_packet, out_packet;
assign in_packet = in;
assign out = out_packet;
```